# win32 message loop - should I break or return?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm wondering what the correct return value for a windows message loop is. So far I've used the following:

```
case WM_LBUTTONDOWN: // left mouse button pressed.
    if (condition == true )
    {
        do_something();
    }
break;
```

but I've seen also things like:

```
if (IDC_BUTTON == LOWORD(wParam) && BN_CLICKED == HIWORD(wParam))
{
    do_something();
    return true;
}
break;
```

which one is correct? Should I `return true`? or should I `break?` Does it matter?

**EDIT** does it depend whether I'm interacting with a button press or a mouse movement?

Comment: they're completely different & depends on the context.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore does it depend on the message? what are the difference? when should I use which?

Comment: That's not a message loop, that's a window procedure.  It depends a great deal on how it was programmed, particularly what happens at the bottom with the call to DefWindowProc().  The return value is LRESULT, returning *true* is almost never correct.  But rarely noticed.  It could also be a dialog procedure, return *true* is still wrong but a bit more correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return value is documented on MSDN, as part of the documentation for each message. For example, the documentation for [WM_LBUTTONDOWN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645607%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states that

> If an application processes this message, it should return zero.

For other messages, the return value might be more meaningful. You should always read the documentation, never guess.

Comment: This.  You need to understand the message being handled.  Some messages make sense to do something, but continue passing them on to other window procedures to handle further.  Some you want to say "I've handled this, we're done here."  And some you want to say "I'm going to do some additional processing as part of every message before indicating if this message should be considered done or not."

Answer (score 2):

Whether you `break` or `return` depends upon the context - i.e. what you wish to do **after** processing this message. If you have nothing more to do - you may return immediately.

But when you do return from your message loop - make sure you `return 0;`
According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645607%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): `If an application processes this message, it should return zero`

Answer (score 1):

If you use break, your execution remains in the current function. It allows you to set the result variable and perform some actions uniformaly before returning. But if you return, your execution will get to the calling function and will not continue to execute whatever you have further in the current function. So there is no correct variant - it's up to you to decide what to use: `break` or `return`. It depends on your own design.

For example:

```cpp
bool result;

switch(msg)
{
case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    //do smth...
    result=true;
    break;//execution goes to (3)
case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
    //actions...
    result=true;
    break;//execution goes to (3)
case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
    //some code...
    //no break here! execution continues to the next event
case WM_MWHEELUP:
    //if WM_RBUTTONDOWN occured, execution continues to here and goes on
    result=false;//maybe you need false here, I dont know
    break;//processing WM_RBUTTONDOWN will stop only here, as well as processing WM_MWHEELUP
case WM_USER1:
    //lines of code....
    return true;//do not perform final actions starting from (3), but end up with this function immideately
default:
    result=false;    
}

// (3)
//perform some final actions...

return result;
```

It does not depend on what event you are interacting with.